# How to use the Links list item as target column for a lookup field in SharePoint?

Tags: lookup-column, links-list

I have created a Links list in my SharePoint 2010 site. Also, I have created a default document library. Now I want to create a new column in the document library; the column should be a multiple choice lookup column to the items in the Links list.

When I choose to create that new column, I choose the Links list as the source, but I cannot choose the URL field from the Links as the field to be used for the lookup. Is there anything that I can set in order to make it available? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid lookups only work on fields of type text (for example single line of text, number, calculated column). If you want to point to urls, you'll have to enter them in a separate text field.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that as well. I just thought that there could be some workaround to it. Oh well, it's certainly not the end of the world :)

Comment: A workaround I often use is to run a workflow to copy the information into a text field.